# Why does hg merge keep two copies of a moved file?

Tags: mercurial, merge

I'm getting a strange result when merging two branches after I've moved a bunch of files into various folders. For example, initially I have in the root of the `main` branch:

```
(main)
|-run.py
```

I made a new branch (*moves*) in which I moved a lot of files around (with `hg mv`):

```
(moves)
|-bin/
   |-run.py
```

I get an unexpected result (at least for me) when merging the two branches (`hg up main && hg merge moves`).  Basically the same file appears in the the `main` branch in two locations:

```
(main)
|-run.py
|-bin/
   |-run.py
```

If I do this in a simplified test I get the result I expect:

```
hg init test
cd test
touch file_a
hg add file_a
hg ci -m 'added file_a'
hg branch movement
mkdir files
hg mv file_a files
hg ci -m 'moved file_a'
hg up default
```

At this point `ls` shows the single file `file_a`.

```
(default)
|-file_a
```

After the merge `hg merge movement`, as I expect, `file_a` is in the folder `files` and not in the root anymore.

```
(default)
|-files/
   |-file_a
```

I'm lost trying to figure out why I am not getting the same result with my real repository.

**UPDATE**

Digging in mercurial logs and looking at what changed:

```
>hg status --change 457  -C
A bin/run.py
  run.py
R run.py
```

So it looks to me that the file was moved and the move registered. After the merge, when the two files are both present I can only get the log (`hg log -f`) for `run.py` in the main directory. For `bin/run.py` it prints: `abort: cannot follow file not in parent revision: "bin/run.py"`. However, after I commit the merge then `hg log -f` works for both files.

Answer (score 1):

As your simplified test shows that's not a proper behavior.
I would check the revision history of run.py file in moves branch to see if it has the information that it was moved.

Comment: Added some log info above.

Comment: It's really strange. Can you see something strange when comparing outputs of hg log commands for both files?

Comment: The only difference is that the log for the original run.py goes back to the revision when I renamed the file. For the bin/run.py it shows also the changes made after the move. Looks like somehow the file has been duplicated and despite Mercurial having registered the move it things the files are separate. I have made a clean copy of the repository and started a new repo. Can't waste too much time on this. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The latest Mercurial release (2.7) fixes my problem. Could have been caused by [this bug](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3984).